# Xcode 9 Typedef redefinition with different types ('NSString *' vs 'AVMediaType')

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After updated to Xcode 9.0 final, I can't build my Objective-C project. It said:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVMediaFormat.h:14:20: Typedef redefinition with different types ('NSString *' vs 'AVMediaType')

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVAssetWriter.h:135:41: Type argument 'AVMediaType' is neither an Objective-C object nor a block type

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVCaptureDevice.h:513:102: Nullability specifier 'nullable' cannot be applied to non-pointer type 'AVMediaType'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to see where you are using AVMediaType in your project such as when using ffmpeg library and rename 'AVMediaType' to something else everywhere it is referenced in ffmpeg like in avutil.h avformat.h avcodec.h etc.